# ¿Como usar el bootstrap instalado desde package de dependecias con npm?

Tags: css, bootstrap, reactjs, npm, babel

He instalado el bootstrap con npm y para utilizar el module estoy intentando usar un import desde un component

`import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';`

Comment: Buscas usarlo como componentes o como hoja de estilos global?

Comment: como hoja de estilo global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generalmente lo importas en index.js y de esa manera puedes usarlo en tus componentes

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: pude resolver, y en cuanto al código se me hizo fácil corregir y sucedió success con tu respuestas :) gracias